# nvd3: set background fill behind line chart

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, nvd3.js

I have some data which is used in one place to make a heatmap, and in another place to make a line chart.  I want to put a gradient behind the line chart so that points on the line chart appear in front of the color used in the heatmap.

If I understand right, all that's needed is to set the fill on the appropriate svg element, but I haven't found any indication that nvd3 will help me find that element.  Can I do this with the nvd3 API, or do I have to reverse-engineer the chart to find or insert that element?

Comment: @JoshJordan, by "nv API" I mean the API exposed through the object named "nv".  There is no object named "nvd3"; that nv is built on d3 is, in my mind, an implementation detail not related to my use of the API.  How is replacing every use of "nv" with "nvd3" an improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's still no indication that nvd3 will help with this, but it turns out it's easy to find the appropriate element to fill.

In short, it's `element_to_fill = d3_object_of_svg_with_chart.select("rect");`

There are at least 2 caveats to this:

1. The gradient must be defined in a `linearGradient` tag within a `<defs>` tag in the same `<svg>` tag.  Adding this with jQuery calls doesn't work, it must be added with d3 calls.
2. The height of this element may be wrong, especially if the legend is more than one line, but is fixed by `lineChart_object.update();`

The code looks a bit like this:

```js
nv.addGraph( function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
    //... set up chart as before
    var chart_d3 = d3.select("#"+container_element_id).append("svg");
    chart_d3.datum(chart_data_array);
    chart_d3.call(chart);

    // Now draw the gradient background:
    var grad_id = some_unique_id_string;
    var defs_d3 = chart_d3.insert( "defs", ":first-child" ); // define gradient
    var grad_d3 = defs_d3.append("linearGradient").attr("id",grad_id).attr("x1","0%").attr("y1","0%").attr("x2","0%").attr("y2","100%");
    grad_d3.append("stop").attr("offset","0%").attr("style","stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1");
    grad_d3.append("stop").attr("offset","100%").attr("style","stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);stop-opacity:1");
    var fill_d3 = chart_d3.select("rect"); // get nvd3's background rect
    fill_d3.attr("style",null); // nvd3 applies style="opacity: 0.5;"
    fill_d3.attr("fill","url(#"+grad_id+")");
    chart.update(); // nvd3 gets height wrong before update
    return chart;
} );
```

For a complete example, see [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGYzMJ?editors=101).  (The styling there is very different than expected, but the background gradient is working.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25078620/776723) about line chart style.)